# How Selenium webdriver screenshot capturing method can be used while reading a data from .xlsx file using POI?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

As in Excel multiple rows are present, having different set of data and I want to take screenshot for each and every step like this

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot1.png"));
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    File scrFile1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile1, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot2.png"));
```

How the same will be repeated for each Excel row.

As if I hardcode the value of "Screenshot1, ...2, etc." at the end I will get only 2 screenshots instead of 2 screenshots for each row record.

Comment: you want to take screenshot at every activity or just when u call Driver.get(url) ???

Comment: You can create a method which takes screen shot and saves the file. Call this method before navigating to a website. This will ensure screen shot is captured and saved for each and every line of excel. Also for saving you can use time stamp which will ensure a new file is created every time and does not throw file exists error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a FileName string instead of hardcoded file path, You can pass row number in screenshot file name for better identifications of screenshot file.

```
File ScreenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
StringBuilder FileName = new StringBuilder("C:\\tmp");
FileName.append(ScreenshotName);
FileName.append("_");
FileName.append(rownumber);
FileName.append(".jpeg");
FileUtils.copyFile(ScreenShot, new File(FileName.toString()));
```